# Float Place Holder Prints Extra Zeroes

Tags: python, dictionary

Here's an excerpt of my code:

```
elif choice == "3":
    print("====================================\nPRINTING LIST...")
    #prints in this format: item name              item price      item quant and accesses the keys
    for i in glist:
        print("%s              %f              %d" %(i["item"], i["price"], i["quant"]))
```

Basically, what the program does is ask the user for an item, price of the item, and it's quantity stores it in a dictionary and prints it in a formatted format. When the user chooses 3, it should execute the aforementioned blocks of code.

The expected outcome should go something like this:
USER INPUT:
Item: Egg
Price: 2
Quant: 3

EXPECTED RESULTS:
Egg         2.00        3

The result I am getting:
USER INPUT:
Item: Egg
Price: 2
Quant: 3

EXPECTED RESULTS:
Egg         2.0000000000        3

How do I remove the excess zeros in the item price?

I haven't tried anything yet because I am clueless on what it is I should do.

Comment: See https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-format-float-to-string/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting decimal digits of an float number? --PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66241849/formatting-decimal-digits-of-an-float-number-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%0.2f` in print function

For example

```
elif choice == "3":
    print("====================================\nPRINTING LIST...")
    #prints in this format: item name              item price      item quant and accesses the keys
    for i in glist:
        print("%s              %0.2f              %d" %(i["item"], i["price"], i["quant"]))
```

This code giving Egg 2.00 3